# Combining sentence embeddings of two different models (sBERT and mBERT)

Tags: nlp, bert, huggingface

I am working on a chatbot that helps students. 
So, I wanted to make use of bert model which has better performance on mathematics, which lead to me to math-bert, but the paper on it said that it was trained only on mathematical corpus, which means it wont have great performance on general sentences (example in image), so is there a method to combine sentence-bert and math-bert?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Or, the only way is to train bert model from scratch using corpus used for sentence-bert and math-bert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to directly use GPT for maths.

Currently GPT-3 is one of the best models to answer maths problems, but it requires a poweful hardware.

https://openai.com/blog/grade-school-math/

Nevertheless, you can have good results using GPT-2:

https://github.com/openai/grade-school-math

https://github.com/openai/grade-school-math/blob/master/grade_school_math/train.py

I recommend starting with the smallest model (124M parameters). It should be enough if it is just a chatbot to solve classic maths problems.

https://huggingface.co/gpt2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to combine sentence-BERT and math-BERT models to improve the performance of a chatbot that helps students. There are a few different approaches that you could take to do this:

Fine-tuning: One approach would be to fine-tune a BERT model on a combined dataset that includes both mathematical and non-mathematical sentences. This would allow the model to learn both types of language and improve its performance on a wide range of tasks. You could use the sentence-BERT and math-BERT models as pre-trained models and then fine-tune them on your own dataset using the transformers library in Python.

Ensemble learning: Another approach would be to use ensemble learning, which involves training multiple models and combining their predictions to make a final prediction. You could train a sentence-BERT model and a math-BERT model separately, and then combine their predictions using a simple voting or averaging technique.

Multi-task learning: Another option would be to use multi-task learning, which involves training a single model to perform multiple tasks simultaneously. You could design a multi-task learning model that is able to classify mathematical and non-mathematical sentences and use it to improve the performance of your chatbot.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on building a model to evaluate students' essays and I am trying to combine word embeddings from bert, bertweet and roberta. I am able to combine the cls tokens from these models. My question is on what encoding and attention masks, I will be fitting the final model as I have three sets of word encodings and attention masks. This is the model structure:- [image]